# 301 redirect for similar pages of a website

Tags: .htaccess

I want help on code for 301 redirect for the following case.

Google considers the following four pages to be similar.

www.domain.com/contact
www.domain.com/contact/
www.domain.com/contact.html
www.domain.com/contact.html/

Kindly please help how to redirect to just www.domain/contact in rthe above case. What should I add to the .htaccess ? I want to do it for all the pages for my website to avoid duplication.

Regards,
Ayesha

Comment: found the answer myself: RedirectMatch 301 ^/pagename/\.html$ /pagename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer myself:

Add following to .htaccess

RedirectMatch 301 ^/pagename/.html$ /pagename

works for .html and .php or other extensions